# Difference between git reset --hard and git checkout

Tags: git, version-control, git-checkout, git-reset

Let's say I want to undo all changes introduced by previous commits.

As far as I understand, `git reset --hard <specified commit>` will remove all commits up until the specified commit, and undo all changes.
On the other hand `git checkout <specified commit>` will change my directory to reflect the specified commit.

So if I `git reset` after `git checkout` will it have the same result as `git reset --hard`?

Alternatively, if I simply `git commit` after `git checkout`, will the newly created commit overwrite the existing commits?

Comment: If you commit after the checkout you will a branching point, not an overwrite.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Commits* are trees, *branches* are pointers to some commits, and `HEAD` (alias: `@`) is a pointer to some branch or to some commit (‘detached `HEAD`’).

`git checkout <commit>` moves *the `HEAD`*, index, and working tree to the specified commit, and keeps any local changes in the index and working tree [if possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22055552/2326961), otherwise the operation is aborted. When you do this, the `HEAD` becomes detached. You will see this message, which is pretty self-explanatory:

> You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make
> experimental changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits
> you make in this state without impacting any branches by performing
> another checkout.
>
> If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you
> may do so (now or later) by using -b with the checkout command again.
> Example:
>
> git checkout -b new_branch_name

So **you will not loose any changes in the working tree and index**, and **you will not loose any commits with it**.* It is a safe operation.

`git reset --hard <commit>` moves *the branch pointed to by `HEAD`* or the `HEAD` if it is detached, index, and working tree to the specified commit. So **you will loose all the changes in the working tree and index**. Additionally, if you're moving to some older commit and the newer commits are not in some other branch, **you will loose these newer commits too**. It is not a safe operation so don't do this unless you really understand what you're doing.

See also [these great answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-you-undo-the-last-commit) for information about how to undo a commit.

You might also benefit from using a GUI tool like SourceTree.

---

* Well, unless you're already in detached `HEAD` state on some dangling commit, but normally you shouldn't worry.

Answer (score 3):

> So if I `git reset` after `git checkout` will it have the same result as `git reset --hard`?

No. `git reset` (with --hard, or any other option) resets the HEAD, so you always lose commits, unless you are not specifying any commit to reset to.

After you do `git checkout <commit>` you are in a detached HEAD state, so `git reset` is a bit pointless because you won't be resetting any branch.

> Alternatively, if I simply `git commit` after `git checkout`, will the newly created commit overwrite the existing commits?

No. Because again, you are in a detached HEAD state. You are essentially creating commits in a ghost branch.

The safest thing is to always create a new branch with `git checkout -b` and once you are sure you want to reset your other branch, then do `git reset --hard`.